# A conceptual Query regarding measurement during a Quantum Algorithm

Tags: measurement, mathematics

I am new to Quantum Computing and my original background is in Computer Science thus this possible trivial query.

**Case 1:** Given a set of $N$ Q-bit System in some superposition state $I_0$. Let us perform a measurement on the system. The system would collapse to some classical state. Now let us perform some $k$ quantum operations such that it reaches some new superposition state $I_a$.

**Case 2:** Now, In second case we are provided an identical superposition state $I_0$ to begin with. But without performing measurement and collapsing it to a classical state we perform the same $k$ quantum operations as in the first case to achieve a new superposition state $I_b$

Is there any such set of $k$ operations possible so that the final quantum states $I_a \neq I_b$? Can someone please provide an example for this? And if not is there a proof (with reference)?

Please consider its a layman query while answering.

Comment: I suppose it depends on precisely what you're hoping to get from the statement $I_a\neq I_b$. So, with the aim of clarifying this: what about the case of the $k$ quantum operations actually being the trivial "do nothing" step. Now you know $I_b=I_0$ while, assuming $I_0$ was some superposition, then  $I_a\neq I_0$. Job done? (The other version of the question that I can think of might be "is there every a sequence of unitaries + measurements such that I can distinguish, with certainty, which case we have?")

Comment: In my experience, doing quantum algorithm is rather similar to doing graph algorithms... If you have done Djikstra or other graph algorithms, the same flavor of situations with exponentially entangled/tensored states each having to be kept track of arise. Quantum algorithms are completely deterministic, since the probability numbers jumble in fully deterministic/reversible ways. When a "measurement" is performed, we have to discard all data in the other branches and confine ourselves to the measured branch is all...

Comment: @DaftWullie Thank you. I understand but do nothing though perfectly fine seems like a hack :) . $I_a \neq I_b$ essentially states the 2 super-position states would be different. I got my answer below. I don't understand "is there a..." part..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum gates (which I assume you mean by "quantum operations") are reversible: applying a gate to different "input" states results in different "output" states. This means that as long as $I_0$ is a superposition and the state of the system after the measurement in case 1 is different from $I_0$, the states after applying *any* sequence of quantum gates will be different in cases 1 and 2.

Comment: thank you. I understand.